# NSBezierCurve not drawing lines

Tags: swift, cocoa

I tried drawing on NSImageView, and if I want to draw an oval, it works. If I try drawing a line, it fails. Why?
My object declaration:

```
class MyImgView: NSImageView {

var color = NSColor.greenColor()
var point1 = NSPoint()
var point2 = NSPoint()

init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.point1 = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.point2 = NSPoint(x: bounds.width, y:bounds.height)
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    //var path = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: dirtyRect)
    var path = NSBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 10
    path.moveToPoint(point1)
    path.lineToPoint(point2)
    color.setFill()
    path.fill()

}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving point2 initialization in drawRect ? Inside init bounds property gives wrong value especially if you are using auto layout

Comment: @zelib I am not using auto layout, and no point2 coordinate I tried worked. It was from 50 to 200 pixels (when I hardcoded it), and my window size is larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `path` has no area, but just a line.
`color.setFill()` and `path.fill()` should be `color.setStroke()` and `path.stroke()`:

```
class MyImgView: NSImageView {

    var color = NSColor.greenColor()
    var point1 = NSPoint()
    var point2 = NSPoint()

    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.point1 = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.point2 = NSPoint(x: bounds.width, y:bounds.height)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        //var path = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: dirtyRect)
        var path = NSBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = 10
        path.moveToPoint(point1)
        path.lineToPoint(point2)
        color.setStroke() // <-- HERE
        path.stroke() // <-- and HERE

    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, I see logic, yet nothing appeared when I copy-pasted it, for some reason. I am using Xcode 6 beta (about to update in couple hours)